# Reverse direction for arrow keys in the map window in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shortcuts

Currently the arrow up moves the window up and the data downwards - I would like to reverse this behavior to match the mining software that I am using.  There must be some Python Code somewhere to do this but have not been able to find it.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: To add to Ian, are you able to add a picture to explain the situation as it is not yet clear to me

Comment: Hi MarcM and Ian, by using the arrow keys on the keyboard, one can pan around the QGIS map window.  I would like to reverse the direction that the arrows move the map window.

Comment: There isn't any mention of reversing the pan direction with arrow keys in the General Tools. https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#zooming-and-panning

Comment: Nope - I did have a very hard look both in here, in the QGIS help and on the net in general - nada, nix, nuthin!